# How to check the versions of packages installed via environment.yml as I didn't mention any version of the packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I recently started using environment.yml and it has been convenient at the very least but I didn't use to mention version of any package as usually I wanted the latest one available.

So now one of my packages might need a downgrade to aptly work with another package. Is there a way you can check version of all the packages that have are in the current conda environment?

I have attached the environment.yml

```
name: hsam
dependencies:
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - seaborn
  - scikit-learn
  - rasterio
  - geopandas
  - fiona
```

I am getting a blank from terminal while trying to check the version of the package.

Comment: After activating your environment, type `conda list` at the anaconda prompt.